# Mongo DB Query on List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

i have the sample JSON as below.

```
{
        "subscriber": {
            "id": "123",
            "custom_field1": "0",
            "custom_field2": "0"
        },
        "subscriptions": [{
            "12": {
                "subs_id": "111",
                "state": "5",
            }
        }, {
            "13": {
                "subs_id": "222",
                "state": "8",
            }, {
            "14": {
                "subs_id": "111",
                "state": "8",
            }
        }]
     }
```

I am able to query on Mongo DB like

> ***db.testTable.find({"subscriber.id":"123"});***

And i am able to get the results too using the above query.

Now i want to filter the data on **subscriptions** array which consist of **"subs_id" = "111"**.

I tried like below

> ***db.testTable.find({"subscriptions.subs_id":"111"});***

which is not giving me results. Can some one suggest me how to do this.

Note: I understand that its in **List< Map < String, Map < String, String > > >** format and i am querying on value portion of Map object. But not able to get any clue how to fetch the results.

Comment: you should try fixing subscriptions  by changing it to List of embedded documents. something like this `{"subs_key":"12",
            "subs_id": "111",
            "state": "5",
        }` and you can find the subscription using `db.testTable.find({"subscriber.id":"123", "subscriptions.subs_id":"111"},{"subscriptions.$":1);`

Comment: agreeing with what sagar said. if mongo would have wild card field name search then there would be a different story but right now your document probably need tweaking. why to label your docs with numbers ? is there a reason ?

Comment: Thanks for inputs. But i can't change the input data format as it is coming from client end. Just need to filter data in the format given..  Any suggestions without data tweaking is appriciated..!

Comment: You're just missing the key value `12` in your example. `db.testTable.find({"subscriptions.12.subs_id":"111"})` works.

Comment: Dear @DaveCoast Please find the updated JSON. There can be multiple values with **subs_id=111** but its key can be different.

Comment: @Manindar Other option will be to retrieve the subscriber and filter out the subscriptions in java code. This will be okay solution as you only seem to care about one subscriber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can use $where

```
db.testTable.find({$where : "for(var i in this.subscriptions){for(var j in this.subscriptions[i]){if(this.subscriptions[i][j]['subs_id'] && this.subscriptions[i][j]['subs_id'] === '111'){return true;}}}"});
```

Don't curse me, the db design is faulty imo. You might need to rethink your db structure for efficient and 'pleasant' queries.

[$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) is also costly, since it doesn't uses index, it's basically a scan on all document hence comparatively slow.

Also
 I would like to clarify that subscriptions field is basically `List<Map<String,Map<String,String>>>`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its working fine. can u suggest any link for implementing the similar query using JAVA code.

Comment: Well, all java drivers supports $where in one way or other, Which one you plan to use is up to you. in case if you want to use spring-data-mongodb I couldn't find a straightforward way but you can create a BasicQuery with string, in String you can pass the whole clause which we have inside find parameter.  as an example see line number 223 : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/query/StringBasedMongoQueryUnitTests.java